# PHP exec call nohup command

Tags: java, php, jar, exec, nohup

I am currently using PHP exec() to call nohup command that execute a jar file as a background task on the server and get process PID,However it seems there are something incorrect with my script that the command doesn't get executed.

my code looks like this:

```
$command="nohup java -jar /path/to/jarfile/search.jar -k='keyword' -lang='en' -dir='/out' -profile='n' > outputlog.out 2>&1&";

exec($command);
```

However,when I try to execute the command without the "> outputlog.out 2>&1&" it works fine.but it will occuping the webpage till it finishes,which it not i want.

Can anyone help?

Comment: try `>/dev/null 2>&1 &` instead of `> outputlog.out 2>&1&";`

Comment: Thank you for replying,this doesn't work either.

Comment: can you test it with out the java code, just call something else that takes a while

Comment: I wrote a simple java program it works fine with "nohup java -jar exe.jar" but once i try to run as a background task it doesn't work.don't even has a error message.

Comment: check the user permissions

Comment: Hey Dagon,thank you for your suggestion,I grant the permission,it works,but it still doesn't return me the PID of the process,any idea how to receive the pid?

Comment: are you using `& echo $!` to return the pid ?